# Get data back from angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a directive which I called `my-tree`, and I'm calling this directive from a view `exemple-tree-view.html` as following:

```
<my-tree ng-model="sampleTreeView.listNoeuds" ... />
```

this view's controller called `sampleTreeView`.

In my directive's link function I have a function that returns some data, which I affect to scope variable declared in the directive's controller, as following :

```
function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {

   //some code

    scope.createNode = function ($event) {
        var sel = $(element).jstree(true).create_node($($event.currentTarget)[0].closest('.jstree-node').id);
        if (sel) {
            $(element).jstree(true).edit(sel, '', function (node, success, cancelled) {
                scope.treeActionsResult.createdNode  = node;
            });
        }
    };

    //some code
}
```

My question is how can I get the `scope.treeActionsResult.createdNode` value in the `sampleTreeView` controller, since it's the controller for the `exemple-tree-view.html` where I call my directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared scope between the directive and controller by removing the scope property

like in this example:

```
MyApp.directive('studentDirective', function () {
return {
    template: "{{student.name}} is {{student.age}} years old !!",
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
});
```

Still you have the $scope object, but in this case the scope object is shared with parent controller's scope.

You can read more about it fron the following link
[Understanding Scope in AngularJs Custom Directive](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/11/understanding-scopes-in-angularjs-custom-directives.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't create isolated scope for your directive then you can access directive scope values from your controller. like bellow

your controller and directive:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 1;
});

app.directive('myTree', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.values = {};
      scope.values.price = 1234;
    }
  };
});
```

then use in your html like:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>value {{values.price}}</p>
    <my-tree att="{{attValue}}"></my-tree>
  </body>
```

here `values.price` shown from directive in `MainCtrl`